# Поочердное открытие файлов

Tags: php, foreach

Всем доброго времени суток! Возникла такая проблема с поочередным открытием файлов из директории, для начала я считал список файлов в массив:

```
$path_dir = 'old_kulichi/stihi';
function getArrayFiles($path_dir) {
$array_path = array();
$dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path_dir);
foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir) as $val) {
    if($val->isFile()) {
        $array_path[] = $val->getPathname();
    }
}
return $array_path;
}
```

помогите решить проблему нубу, не могу разобраться с циклом foreach

Comment: В чем сама проблема? Я протестировал Ваш код - возвращает список файлов.

Comment: @Uchiha1992, Перефразируйте, пожалуйста, Ваш вопрос: исправьте грамматические ошибки, правильно расставьте запятые. Если ещё добавите побольше уточняющей информации, то Вы ускорите получение ответа.

Comment: д**и**р**е**ктория

Answer (score 1):

```
function getArrayFiles($path_dir)
{
    $array_path = array();
    $dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path_dir);

    foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir) as $val)
        if ($val->isFile())
            $array_path[] = $val->getPathname();

    return $array_path;
}

foreach (getArrayFiles($path_dir) as $file) 
{
    $f = fopen($file, 'r');

    //Делаем что-то важное c файлом

    fclose($f);
}
```

Comment: а где getArrayFiles(), в скобках что нужно написать?

Comment: @Uchiha1992, не думали, что путь к папке?

Comment: я когда прописываю туда путь, то бишь переменную $path_dir, программа виснет